# Increment button clicks separately in Mithril component composition

Tags: javascript, closures, mithril.js, factory-method

I am confused by how components are composed in Mithril.js. In the example below, I create a button component that keeps a private count of the number of button clicks. If I mount two such components (buttons 1 and 2 below) to two mount points ("m1" and "m2" below) individually, I can initialise and increment the counts of button clicks *separately* and correctly.

However, if I wrap two button components (buttons 3 and 4 below) inside a larger component and mount this wrapper component to a mount point ("m3"), the button clicks do not increment at all. What is wrong here and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This works:</h1>
    <div id="m1"></div>
    <div id="m2"></div>
    <h1>This doesn't work:</h1>
    <div id="m3"></div>

    <script>
      // The factory method to generate a button component
      function createButton(options) {
        let {title, count} = options;
        return {view: () => [
          m("span", title),
          m("button", {onclick: function() {count++}}, count + " clicks"),
        ]};
      };      

      (function() {
        // this works
        m.mount(document.getElementById("m1"), createButton({title: "button 1 ", count: 0}));
        m.mount(document.getElementById("m2"), createButton({title: "button 2 ", count: 10}));

        // this doesn't work
        m.mount(document.getElementById("m3"), {view: () => [
          m("div", [m(createButton({title: "button 3 ", count:  0}))]),
          m("div", [m(createButton({title: "button 4 ", count: 10}))]),
        ]});
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version is creating a brand-new component with brand-new arguments on each redraw, so the `count` value is obliterated on each event.

If you instead use mithril's [closure components](https://mithril.js.org/components.html#closure-components) it'll do what you're looking for.

```
// Button closure component
function createButton(vnode) {
  let {title, count} = vnode.attrs;

  return {
    view: () => [
      m("span", title),
      m("button", {onclick: function() {count++}}, count + " clicks"),
    ]
  };
};      

(function() {
  m.mount(document.getElementById("m3"), {view: () => [
    m("div", [m(createButton, {title: "button 3 ", count:  0})]),
    m("div", [m(createButton, {title: "button 4 ", count: 10})]),
  ]});
})();
```

https://jsbin.com/mazujij/2/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That fully explains what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if button components 3 and 4 are created **beforehand** (rather than on-the-fly inside the view() body of the wrapper component), the buttons will behave correctly. However, I still don't know why buttons 1 and 2 can be defined on-the-fly but buttons 3 and 4 cannot.

```
    <script>
      (function() {
        // this works
        m.mount(document.getElementById("m1"), createButton({title: "button 1 ", count: 0}));
        m.mount(document.getElementById("m2"), createButton({title: "button 2 ", count: 10}));

        // now this also works
        let b3 = createButton({title: "button 3 ", count:  0});  // created beforehand
        let b4 = createButton({title: "button 4 ", count: 10});  // created beforehand
        m.mount(document.getElementById("m3"), {view: () => [
          m("div", [m(b3)]),
          m("div", [m(b4)]),
        ]});
      })();
    </script>
```